# Only top-level domain redirect using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have some htaccess that looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?joshrodg\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://joshrodgers.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

The first three lines are forcing all of my sites to be https, so we're all good there. The last two lines, I would like to take the `non-www` and the `www` of joshrodg.com and redirect to https://joshrodgers.com/.

My code is working, the thing is, it's working a little too good. I use other paths from joshrodg.com like joshrodg.com/example or joshrodg.com/test but I don't want these paths to redirect. I just want the top-level domain to redirect. I'm thinking this is just a quick tweak and I've tried several pieces of code, but am still getting redirected.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Do you know what the first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive (ie. `^` in your example) does? [See the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) Bear in mind that even when you change this rule, you will still be redirected since 301 _permanent_ redirects are cached persistently by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "just the top level domain" you actually mean requests to the root folder or to the path "/" only. So you need to match exactly that path only:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$  https://joshrodgers.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is a great solution, redirects the `www` and `non-www` from joshrodg.com, but my paths still work just fine! Thank you!!